# Tabulator - ajax, how to restore table header persistence

Tags: javascript, ajax, persistence, tabulator

I'm trying to restore table header order from local storage, but it doesn't work for a header from ajax response.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        placeholder: "No Data Available", //display message to user on empty table
        movableColumns: true, //enable user movable columns
        persistence: {
            columns: true,
        },
        ajaxURL: "/ajax/showall", //ajax URL
        persistenceWriterFunc: function (id, type, data) {
            //id - tables persistence id
            //type - type of data being persisted ("sort", "filter", "group", "page" or "columns")
            //data - array or object of data                

            if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length) {
                // array does not exist, is not an array, or is empty
                // ⇒ do not attempt to process array
                console.log('do not save empty array');
                localStorage.setItem(id + "-" + type, JSON.stringify(data));
            };
        },
        persistenceReaderFunc: function (id, type) {
            //id - tables persistence id
            //type - type of data being persisted ("sort", "filter", "group", "page" or "columns")                
            return data ? JSON.parse(data) : false;
        },

        ajaxResponse: function (url, params, response) {
            this.setColumns(response.header);
            return response.data;
        }
    });
```

Is there some way to do this?
I was trying to use `tableBuilding: function()` etc, but nothing works.
I don't want to send ajax query just to get a table header.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do any of this manually, you enable the persistence module it will do all this for you automatically as long as you have the persistent columns option enabled

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    persistence:{
        columns: true, //persist columns
    }
});
```

See the [Persistence Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/persist) for more information.

Any time the columns are set by your ajax response they will automatically update the local storage options.

You only need to use the ***persistenceWriterFunc*** and ***persistenceReaderFunc*** options if you are trying to replace the inbuilt storage options, which it does not appear you need to do here